# Add a custom post when inserting a new user in Wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I want to add a custom post type (called pupil) into Wordpress when inserting a new user. The `wp_insert_user()` is used for creating new users.

I have this code:

```
function register_user_pupil($user_id) {

    //Count nr of occurences in user-table for submitted email-adress
    $email_form = $_POST['email'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users";
    $sql .= " WHERE user_email = '%s'";    
    $count_users_email = intval($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( $sql, $email)));

    //Check if email (from exists) already exists in the system (in users table)
    //If it doesn't, create new user into variable. If it does, store that user in variable
    //based on email-adress
    if ($count_users_email === 0) {
        $current_user = new WP_User($user_id);
    }
    else {
        $current_user = get_user_by( 'email', $email_form );
    }

    //Create a new pupil custom post-type for this user
    $user_registration_post = array(
      'post_title'      => $current_user->display_name,
      'post_type'       => 'pupil',
      'post_status'     => 'draft',             //This registration cpt is not available for public
      'post_author'     => $current_user->ID
    );
    $postid_pupil = wp_insert_post( $user_registration_post );

    //postid should return something above 0 and not a WP_Error-object
    if (is_array($postid_pupil) || intval($postid_pupil) === 0) {                        
        throw new Exception('Kan inte skapa en elev-registrering');
    }

    //Rest of updating is done by function postsubmit() (saving the pupil CPT)

}
//Hook for handling new users 
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_user_pupil', 10, 3 );
```

The issue is that this function is called **AFTER** the user is inserted, I want it to be executed **BEFORE** the actual user is inserted. I've also tried to use the register_post hook, but this code is not called before the user is inserted anyway.I've also tried to figure out if I could use hooks with `pre_{something}`, but with no luck.

Anyone could me help me? That would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: You want to insert the post for every failed registration attempt and without knowing the user ID? Why?

Comment: I want to do the checking of the users email before, but the ideal would be insert/create the cpt after the user is succesfully created. If the email already exist, I don't want to create a user, but I want to create a CPT for the user with that email.

Comment: Have you already seen [`email_exists()`](http://queryposts.com/function/email_exists/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this a lot harder than it has to be.

1. Run your code on `user_register` and `update_profile`
2. Check to see if the post exists, and create it if not
3. Done. WordPress should take care of the rest.

Something like:

```
function register_user_pupil($user_id) {
  $current_user = new WP_User($user_id);

  $post_args = array(
    'post_title'      => $current_user->data->display_name,
    'post_type'       => 'pupil',
    'post_status'     => 'draft',             //This registration cpt is not available for public
    'post_author'     => $current_user->ID
  );
  $exists = new WP_Query($args);

  if (!$exists->have_posts()) {
    $postid_pupil = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
  }  

  //postid should return something above 0 and not a WP_Error-object
  if (is_array($postid_pupil) || intval($postid_pupil) === 0) {                        
      throw new Exception('Kan inte skapa en elev-registrering');
  }

  //Rest of updating is done by function postsubmit() (saving the pupil CPT)

}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'register_user_pupil');
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_user_pupil');
```

I don't have your CPT and supporting code so I can't really test that but I am pretty sure it is close.

WordPress will enforce unique email addresses so I don't see the point of worrying about that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :-) I think I will figure it out now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing the priority of action, 10 to something like 50

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_user_pupil', 50, 1 );
```

And you've write 3 as number of arguments pass to your function `register_user_pupil` but actually you are using just `$user_id` `function register_user_pupil($user_id)`

1. Increased the priority like, 50
2. Set number of arguments to 1

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please explain why this might fix the problem.